# Laravel Factory

Tags: laravel, eloquent, factory

Hi I am new to creating factories on Laravel and I am setting up a blog website. There is no need for users at this time as it is a draft but I am trying to set up a factory to create dummy blog posts.

I have a Post.php file which looks like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

My PostFactory looks like this

```
use App\Post;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->name,
        'body' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    ];
});
```

but everytime i try to create the records it throws this error "InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory for [App/Post].'"
i know its about linking these files but i cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: The file for your post model should be called `Post.php` and not `posts.php`. Also all those properties that you declared in your model are unnecessary and automatically declared by Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First as mentioned above your file must be named Post.php and not posts.php.

Since you are using App\Post at the beginning of your file, you can simply call `Post::class`
`$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker)`

Another option could also be that you are missing the factories folder in your composer classmap:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
```

If this does not solve the problem, then you might need to post your code where you are calling your factory

**@edit**

[this is pretty good overview over conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)

Comment: Sorry where should the factory be called, in the controller.php etc

Comment: or in your seeder wherever you need some dummy data, but does it work with the changes now?

Comment: changing Post to posts does work, however in my overall system it does not run due to me creating using Post as throughout the system is there anyway to deal with this without changing the system, why does it work for posts rather than Post

Comment: This is because of laravels automatic detection of file names. If followed correctly, Laravel is able to identify all relationships of this kind, by its own. For example it will also detect the database table without you having to specify the `$table`attribute.
I would Simply rename your file to Post.php that should be enough. @cliff12345

Comment: Sorry i don't follow, the class Post is used throughout the system but the tables name is posts. why does the factory not work, is it due to the table being called posts

Comment: @cliff12345 you wrote: `I have a posts.php file which looks like this:`

But the files name must be `Post.php`. Otherwise Laravel won't find the right factory, table name etc.

Comment: Sorry that is my fault the file is called Post.php not posts.php however if i change it to posts.php it runs the factory but if i keep it as Post.php it says it is not found. the exact error "InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory for [App/Post].'"

Comment: And are you calling the factory with: `factory(App\Post)->create()` ?
Did you do a composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: factory(App\Post::class,10)->create() is what i have been using. i am not sure i believe it may be some bug as gave my friend the exact code and it ran fine for him

Comment: Got it working thanks for all the help Aless55!! it was just a bug i killed the terminal and retried